# matplotlib bar chart with individual labels for each bar and a group label

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there any way to label individual bars using matplotlib? The best case would be vertical labelling under each bar to avoid overlaps

For example the red bar should have the x-label as red, the green one as green and the blue one as blue. The main group 'A, B, C, D' remains as it is.

Also, is there any way to produce the legend of the different colors?

Following my code:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

n_groups = 4
bar_width = 0.1
opacity = 0.4
index = np.arange(0, 2*n_groups, 2)

data = [1,2,3,4]
data2 = [5,6,7,8]
chart = plt.bar(index, data, bar_width, color='blue', edgecolor='black')
chart = plt.bar(index+bar_width, data2, bar_width, color='red', edgecolor='black')
chart = plt.bar(index+2*bar_width, data, bar_width, color='green', edgecolor='black')


ax.set_xlabel('y_axis')
ax.set_ylabel('x_axis')
ax.set_title('Title')

plt.xticks(index+bar_width*0.5, ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'))
plt.legend()
plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

and the output is:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The legend is not on because plt wasn't instructed to label the plots. Add something like this to obtain labels in the legend "label='Plot 1'" in your plot line:

```
chart = plt.bar(index, data, bar_width, color='blue',edgecolor='black', label='Plot 1')
chart = plt.bar(index+bar_width, data2, bar_width, color='red', edgecolor='black', label='Plot 2')
chart = plt.bar(index+2*bar_width, data, bar_width, color='green', edgecolor='black', label='Plot 3')
```

This gets you legends.

Comment: thanks for the answer. what about the x axis labels? Thats my main concern.

Comment: if it's useful click on it :D. I don't know how to do the axis labels at the moment, sorry.

Comment: what is the concern on x axis labels?